# Quill - Make Editor wrap text in Div instead of P tag

Tags: reactjs, quill

I have built a Quill text editor in ReactJS with React-Quill. I would like to wrap the generated text in the text editor with a Div tag instead of a P tag. Is this possible?

Overview of my use: When text is generated/edited in the Quill editor it is duplicated in another div on another part of the page. Our use of this editor goes back a few years, and thus was built on an older version of Quill, when the text was generated in Div's. We recently upgraded to Quill 1.0 and when the text is generated in P tags it creates unwanted styles that we can't remove. The simplest and least hacky solution would be to generate div's instead of p tags, but I have no idea if that's even possible.

Does anyone know more about this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just change the tagName of the default Block:

```
var Block = Quill.import('blots/block');
Block.tagName = 'div';
Quill.register(Block);
```

Working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/brgvPR

Comment: This does what the question was asking for, but I noticed that it also appends an extra blank line at the end (<div><br></div>), while the default <p> block behavior doesn't. Any way to prevent the extra blank line?

Comment: @georaldc did you happen to solve this or get a response from jhchen ?

Comment: In my case I just did this since I didn't want to save markup if there's nothing entered: MyQuill.getText().trim().length == 0 ? "" : MyQuill.root.innerHTML;

Comment: From code (https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/develop/blots/block.js#L127):
Block.defaultChild = Break;

try to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I am using next.js

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const ReactQuill = dynamic(async () => {
        const ReactQuill = await import('react-quill');
        const { Quill } = ReactQuill.default;
        const Block = Quill.import('blots/block');
        Block.tagName = 'div';
        Quill.register(Block);

        return ReactQuill;
    }, { ssr: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this in native Javascript and that worked for me:

```
var Block = Quill.import('blots/block');
Block.tagName = 'div';
Block.blotName = "P";
Quill.register(Block);
```