# p:textEditor <br> line separator instead of <p>

Tags: primefaces, quill

I am using JSF (PrimeFaces) tag p:textEditor for my forum. This tag use Quill rich text editor. Default behavior is wrapping every line in blocks (wraping in paragraphs tags p  /p):

```
<p>line1</p> 

<p>line2</p> ....
```

And it does not looks nice, because of output too much spaces between lines. 
Instead, I need to get like this (use tag br/ between lines):

```
<br/> line1
<br/>line2 .....
```

For example, PrimeFaces extension has tag `pe:ckEditor`, that use ckEditor (rich text editor). And I can change its behavior just adding `"config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;"` in `config.js` file.

Is there in `p:textEditor` and its Quill (rich text editor) same ability or some another way that can fix my problem?

Comment: Check my improvements to your Q. Especially the title and tags

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45496023/quill-make-editor-wrap-text-in-div-instead-of-p-tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking into feedback of Quill`s owner -
 https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1074 . And I checked all new versions after this feedback.
 So yet Quill does not has this ability. The owner suggests to use css-style for fixing this behaviour (adjust paddings). Yes, it can resolve a problem of big spaces, but:
1) this way is not so comfortable;
2) this way is not suitable for forum`s quotations, because separate every line in own quote.

[Here](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/252) the problem is discussed and [here](https://codepen.io/farnabaz/pen/VpdaGW) is some js approach to fix it. But I am not going to use it because I use Quill built in JSF library. So I switch to pe:ckEditor and ckEditor rich text editor